# How can I make a li-ion charger using logic gates with auto cut-off facilities?

Tags: digital-logic, battery-charging, electricity, battery-chemistry

I'm recently assigned a project to make a battery charger, using logic gates. But I have no idea how to proceed. I'm in need of guidance. 
I have basic knowledge but not so deep. So I think I can design it, but I just need a push-up.

Comment: [This is what happens if your charger doesn't work right.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YuKF8XfCVKQ)

Comment: Consider using a commercially available module rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: _"I'm recently assigned a project to make a battery charger, using logic gates."_ - can you provide any more details? eg. the type and number of logic gates available, any other components allowed, battery specifications?

Comment: Any number of logic gates can be used, the charger is mainly for li-ion battery and yes other components are allowed. The project needs to have logic gates. I'm wanting the gates to cut-off the circuit when the battery is charged.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm recently assigned a project to make a battery charger, using logic gates

Sounds like a *mission impossible* to me, you simply can't make a Li-Ion battery charger using only logic gates. You can't. **period**.

To properly and safely charge a Li-Ion battery you need to have a **well defined** voltage reference available. This is needed to make sure that charging stops when the battery voltage is around 4.1 to 4.3 V.

With only logic gates available there is **no way** to create or detect such a voltage accurately enough.

Whoever gave you that assignment is either joking or doesn't have a clue.

Comment: Actually I also am willing to make the circuit auto cut-off when it's charged.

Comment: Your comment: a) repeats what is already in your question b) shows that you didn't get the point I make in my answer. I suggest that you get studying and learn: 1) how Li-Ion batteries need to be treated, start at: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries 2) search for "Li-Ion charging circuits" and figure out how they work and how that relates to 1). Note how the charging circuits are **analog** ciruits. If there is any logic it is for control functions only.